# Microsoft ICertAdmin2 Interface from Python ctypes

Tags: python, windows, dll, ctypes

I'm trying to use the Microsofts ICertAdmin2 interface from Python using ctypes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383234(v=vs.85).aspx

So far I can load the Certadm.dll. e.g.

```
import ctypes
# Load DLL into memory.
dll = ctypes.WinDLL ("c:\\windows\\system32\\Certadm.dll")
```

However, I'm not sure what I now need to do to access the methods from within ICertAdmin2 e.g.
ICertAdmin2::ImportKey.

Any guidance would be really appreciated.

UPDATE

Now using the Python 'comtypes' library. This is what I'm trying.

```
>>import comtypes
>>certadmin = CreateObject("CertificateAuthority.Admin") 
>>certadmin._ICertAdmin__com_DenyRequest('WIN-3CF41NBPT85\cjndem-CA', 42)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
COMError: (-2147024809, 'The parameter is incorrect.', (u'CCertAdmin::DenyRequest: The         parameter is incorrect. 0x80070057 (WIN32: 87)', u'CertificateAuthority.Admin', None, 0, None))
```

UPDATE 3

This seems to work now:

```
>>import comtypes
>>from comtypes.client import CreateObject
>>out = comtypes.BSTR('')
>>certadmin = CreateObject("CertificateAuthority.Admin")
>>certadmin._ICertAdmin2__com_GetArchivedKey('ca1\\simpleca', 51, 1 , out)
>>print out

BSTR(u'MIIiHwYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIiEDC...........
```

However this:

```
>>import comtypes
>>from comtypes.client import CreateObject
>>out = comtypes.c_long()
>>request = CreateObject("CertificateAuthority.Request")
>>request._ICertRequest2__com_GetIssuedCertificate('ca1\\simpleca', 1, u'-1', out )
>>print out

COMError: (-2147024809, 'The parameter is incorrect.', (u'CCertRequest::GetIssuedCertificate: The parameter is incorrect. 0x80070057 (WIN32: 87)', u'CertificateAuthority.Request', None, 0, None))
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice - So I can do this >>dll = GetModule("C:\\Windows\\System32\\Certadm.dll"). But can't work out what to do next. Docs seem to be a little obtuse.

Comment: beware, afaik, comtypes won't wotks with 3.3 No need to load the DLL. You must create an instance of a "CertificateAuthority.Admin" COM class.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I can now call some of the methods within CertAdmin2. e.g. _ICertAdmin__com_DenyRequest(). But I'm having trouble with typing. Any chance you could provide an example?

Comment: I need create an instance of "ICertRequest2" interface COM class. How do you get the correct name for this?

Comment: Will try to help this evening, no promises.

Comment: Thanks very much! BTW I have moved on a bit. The update 3 above seems to work now. But I'm having a problem with the ICertRequest2 interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last parameter of `GetIssuedCertificate` is a pointer to a LONG. Use `byref()` to pass it.
Also you should pass a BSTR as first and third arg.

```
out = request.GetIssuedCertificate( 'ca1\\simpleca' ), 1, None )
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm getting the following COM Error now: COMError: (-2147024809, 'The parameter is incorrect.', (u'CCertRequest::GetIssuedCertificate: The parameter is incorrect. 0x80070057 (WIN32: 87)', u'CertificateAuthority.Request', None, 0, None))

Comment: Not sure if it the CA returning that or a problem with the code!