# Using python to insert a block into autocad document, unsuccessfully

Tags: python, autocad, comtypes

I am using Python to insert a block into autocad document.The code below:

```
import comtypes.client
app = comtypes.client.GetActiveObject("AutoCAD.Application")
ms = app.ActiveDocument
files = r"C:\Users\TOM\Desktop\02python\516.00-501.50.dwg"
insertionPnt = [0,0,0]
ms.ModelSpace.InsertBlock(insertionPnt, files, 1, 1, 1, 0)
```

The block is inserted into the document, but the modelspace doesn't display. The exceptions are:

```
File "C:\Users\TOM\Documents\002pybookcode\backup_code\test.py", line 10, in <module>
    ms.ModelSpace.InsertBlock(insertionPnt, files, 1, 1, 1, 0)
_ctypes.COMError: (-2147024809, '\xb2\xce\xca\xfd\xb4\xed\xce\xf3\xa1\xa3', (None, None, None, 0, None))
```

I've solved this problem,and the code below is working.

```
import win32com.client
import pythoncom

def POINT(x,y,z):
    return win32com.client.VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_ARRAY | pythoncom.VT_R8, (x,y,z))  

acad = win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoCAD.Application")  
doc = acad.ActiveDocument  
ms = doc.ModelSpace  
files = r"C:\Users\TOM\Desktop\02python\516.00-501.50.dwg"
doc.Utility.Prompt("hello World\n")
pt1= POINT(0.0,0.0,0.0)
ms.InsertBlock(pt1, files, 1.0,1.0,1.0, 0)
```

Comment: thanks   @Padraic Cunningham

Comment: Have you tried looking up what COM error -2147024809 means? Seems like that would be an important clue as to what is wrong...

Comment: sorry,I do not how to highlight the code.

Comment: Not sure if it's the same issue, but in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21686894/microsoft-icertadmin2-interface-from-python-ctypes), COM error -2147024809 means `The parameter is incorrect.`

Comment: ye, maybe the parameter is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Although you seemed to find a solution for the problem I just found a simpler solution directly in the comtypes documentation http://www.pythonhosted.org/comtypes/#converting-data-types where the explain the problem and have an example for inserting a point in Autocad.

In short, change your code to:

```
import array
import comtypes.client
app = comtypes.client.GetActiveObject("AutoCAD.Application")
ms = app.ActiveDocument
files = r"C:\Users\TOM\Desktop\02python\516.00-501.50.dwg"
insertionPnt = array.array('d', [0,0,0])
ms.ModelSpace.InsertBlock(insertionPnt, files, 1, 1, 1, 0)
```